Why does this imagemagick created white image not show transparency but the red one does?
When I use Imagemagick to overlay a pure white rectangle over a larger transparent canvas:
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill white -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" white_box.png
Then I open this image in Photoshop or similar, the transparent canvas appears black.
However, if I create a RED (or any other color) box using the exact same commands, but just changing the white to red or another color, the transparency is preserved fine and looks correct in photoshop et al. i.e.
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill red -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" red_box.png
Here are the two side by side in Photoshop:

My final solution was to check for the color pure white and change it to rgba(255,255,255,.99).  Making it slightly transparent removed the black box. This ultimately was the less than ideal solution.  But would still love to know the "correct" solution.

Works fine for me on IM 6.9.13.7.  What is your IM version?  I note that your example does not match your command.  Your example shows a smaller color image in a black/transparent background. But your code has the background and the color patch the same size.

@fwm42 I resized them in photoshop for the screenshot.  Could be my version possibly?  ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 is what I am on.

@fwm42 unless I am not understanding what you mean, but the inner red/white box should be -size 1082x392 and the transparent canvas is 2203x2203, but in photoshop, I sized them both down to fit better for the screenshot.

Look at your commands above. The transparent size is the same as the size of the white or red rectangle.  I ran both tests and got either a fully white or fully red image.  I will try modifying the transparent size to 2203x2203

Your command is wrong.  Remove the +swap. That works for me.  convert   \( -gravity center -size 2203x2203  -background none  caption:"" \)    \( -size 1082x392 xc:"rgb(255,255,255)" \) -composite       whitebox.png

With the swap you are trying to overlay a large transparent image over the white or red image. -composite does not allow that. It will crop to the size of the first (smaller rectangle). So the result that I get is either just a red or white rectangle of the size specified. You have to overlay the smaller rectangle over the larger transparent image. If you want the other way around, you need to use -layers merge. But that does not use -gravity or -geometry. You would have to use -page or -set page to position the smaller colored rectangle over the transparent image.

@fmw42 Hey check my updates.  I just edited the original post.  How are you viewing the image to verify the black box issue?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@fmw42 wow this is frustrating.  So if I change the color to -fill "rgba(255,255,255,.99)" it works.  So it is something related to the pure white.  I hate to have to hack it, but might have to.

-composite will crop the larger image to the size of the smaller if you use -swap to move the smaller image first in the command line. So your command should not work and you should get a fully colored image white or red and no transparency.  What is your IM version?  Sounds like you have a bug or bad compile.  Why are you adding +swap?  It works fine if you remove the +swap.

@fmw42 as mentioned in my edit/update, simplifying it down to one command: convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill white -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" white_box.png produces the same results/black box so it isn't related to swap or compositing.  And changing the command to convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill rgba(255,255,255,.99) -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" white_box.png fixes it.  But again to view the issue, you would have to look at it in Photoshop or similar.  I tested on IM 6 and 7 with the same results, so not version related.  Either way, I appreciate you chiming in :)

This command convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill white -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" white_box.png works perfectly fine for me. It is a white box inside of a transparent background. You changed -composite to -draw which works differently.  It does look white on black in Photoshop.  But that is a Photoshop issue of ignoring the transparency on a binary image type. I have no idea why they do not recognize the transparency on binary image type. But the red square is colormapped image type and not binary (b/w).  So I guess they then accept the background transparency.

For the white box, you will need to overwrite the png defaults adding -define png_color-type=4 (gray matte) as convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill white -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" -define png:color-type=4 white_box.png. Then it works and looks fine in photoshop.
`

I have posted a discussion on the Imagemagick forum. Tiff output works fine because it is formatted as type grayscale, whereas PNG is saved as type bilevel.  Photoshop does not seem to like binary/bilevel with transparency and drops the transparency.

@fmw42 Why don't you submit your answer above as the preferred answer and I will accept it.  It's better than my answer and a more consistent way of handling it.  The issue in my case isn't really Photoshop, but ffmpeg which will render it as black as well.  Thank you!

This command
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill white -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" white_box.png

works perfectly fine for me. It is a white box inside of a transparent background. You changed -composite to -draw which works differently. It does look white on black in Photoshop. But the red square is colormapped image type and not binary (b/w).
The command works fine for TIFF output. Further investigation indicates that it works for TIFF because TIFF is output as type=grayscale, where as PNG is output as type=bilevel (bitmap in photoshop). I suppose that TIFF does not support a binary type.
For the white box, you will need to overwrite the png defaults adding -define png_color-type=4 (gray matte) as
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill white -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" -define png:color-type=4 white_box.png

Then it works and looks fine in photoshop because the PNG is then saved as type grayscale.
ADDITION
You can also make it work using
convert -size 2000x2000 xc:none -fill white -draw "rectangle 900,900 1100,1100" PNG32:white_box.png

Oddly, that also has a type=bilevel, but photoshop says it is RGB rather than bitmap.

yes confirmed on the PNG32 answer.  I think that is the easiest way of handling this.  Thank you!

I welcome other answers to this, but my solution at the moment is to simply set the color white to rgba(255,255,255,.99).  For some reason, this allows the canvas to be transparent when the overlay color is white.
While not ideal, the color difference is not perceptible and allows the background to be transparent while the foreground stays white.

The reason that works is that the background image is not simple transparency. It is white with partial transparency.  That causes IM to save as type=grayscale rather than type=bilevel(binary).  Photoshop is OK with grayscale type with transparency, but not binary (bilevel)
